# go program to compare two arrays and store the matching elements in third one in golang

Tags: arrays, linux, go, merge, comparison

Hi i am new in go and i just write a program to compare two arrays and stored the matching element in third one but it is not sucessfully executed

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main(){

    var firstarray =[10] int {1,9,12,16,13,11,14,18,8,12}
     var secondarray =[10] int {9,7,15,8,14,19,34,18,13,11}
    var finalarray [] int

     var i,j,mat int

     for i=0; i<=10; i++{

        for j=0; j<=10; j++{

            if firstarray[i] == secondarray[j]{
                finalarray[mat] == secondarray[j]
                mat++
            }
        }
     }

    fmt.Println("matching no is",finalarray)

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to store elements that are common in both `firstarray` and `secondarray`? Then what you want is really a [*set intersection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)). Perhaps Go have some built-in functionality for it?

Comment: use single assignment when you assign value into third array `finalarray[mat] = secondarray[j]` instead of `finalarray[mat] == secondarray[j]`

Comment: "it is not sucessfully executed" isn't much to go on. Please edit your question to specify what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The main errors in your code are accessing arrays out-of-bounds (which you can fix by iterating over the elements in the arrays rather than using indexes), and the construction of the final array (which you can build up using append, rather than assigning to indexes).

You also use `==` to assign, which is a mistake since it's a comparison operator. Single equals `=` is the assignment operator.

Here's a cleaned-up, working version of your code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    firstarray := []int{1, 9, 12, 16, 13, 11, 14, 18, 8, 12}
    secondarray := []int{9, 7, 15, 8, 14, 19, 34, 18, 13, 11}
    var finalarray []int

    for _, a1 := range firstarray {
        for _, a2 := range secondarray {
            if a1 == a2 {
                finalarray = append(finalarray, a2)
            }
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("matching no is", finalarray)

}
```

It would be better to use maps to find the matching elements, since then the code can be O(n) rather than O(n^2).

Comment: Thankyou for this amazing suggestion. your code solved my problems and also i learned something new in go.

Answer (score 1):

Actually! to insert into third array there is `Index out of range` error was generating, So first of all you've to give an index length so that it can point the area into array where you want to store the value.

Also to assign value into third variable you've to use single assignment operator(=) rather than equal(==) operator.

Follow the below example.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main(){

    var firstarray =[10] int {1,9,12,16,13,11,14,18,8,12}
     var secondarray =[10] int {9,7,15,8,14,19,34,18,13,11}
    var finalarray [10]int

     var i,j,mat int

     for i=0; i<10; i++{

        for j=0; j<10; j++{

            if firstarray[i] == secondarray[j]{
                finalarray[mat] = secondarray[j]
                mat++
            }
        }
     }

    fmt.Println("matching no is",finalarray)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type void struct{}
    var member void
    firstarray := map[int]void{1: member, 9: member, 12: member, 16: member, 13: member, 11: member, 14: member, 18: member, 8: member}
    secondarray := map[int]void{9: member, 7: member, 15: member, 8: member, 14: member, 19: member, 34: member, 18: member, 13: member, 11: member}

    var finalarray []int
    for k := range firstarray {
        if _, ok := secondarray[k]; ok {
            finalarray = append(finalarray, k)
        }
    }

    fmt.Println("matching no is", finalarray)
}
```